# NumberFormat parse not strict enough

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` with a `NumberFormat` with Locale.US. So the decimal separator is the point and the grouping separator is the comma.

Now I type the string "1,23" in this text field and move the focus to another component. I would expect the string to disappear (like it does when i type "a" instead of "1,23") because it is obviously not a valid representation of a number when using Locale.US. But instead the text in the text field is changed to "123".

This is because the used `NumberFormat` is not strict when parsing and simply ignores the comma.

**Question**: How can I tell `NumberFormat` to throw a `ParseException` in this case so the text field will be empty after moving the focus to another component?

Test Code:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
dialog.getContentPane().add(panel);

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
textField.setText("1,23");
panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(new JButton("focus"), BorderLayout.EAST);

dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Move the focus from the text field to the button and the text will change to "123".

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question was about Integers, not Doubles. The question here boils down to an over-lenient NumberFormat that does not check if a comma at that position is allowed. Looks like we need a subclass of NumberFormat with stricter checking.

Comment: @RalfH: You are right, this is not a duplicate. I've edited the question to show the underlying use of NumberFormat in the JFormattedTextField.

Comment: How can i get the duplicate label removed from this question? I would like to post my own solution.

Comment: Thanks for reopening the question, but my solution can now be found under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808144/jformattedtextfield-with-strict-parsing-number-format.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use regex and use the match fucntion like this:

```
matches("\\d+([.,])?")
```

Also if you will use `Integer.parseInt(String)` will throw an exception if it will be parsed or you can use `Double.parseDouble(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Number` is just a super class for `Double`, so you could use `Double.parseDouble(...)` and then auto-unboxing should do the rest.