# Java - NumberFormat parsing invalid String with success

Tags: java

I'm trying to check, if an user entered a number in a valid format. But it seems, that invalid String are also parsed with success. An example:

```
final String value1 = "12,85", value2 = "128,598.77";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
format.parse(value1); // ok
format.parse(value2); // ok, but it's not german format
```

Why does format.parse(value2) don't throw an exception?

Comment: See here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782905/numberformat-parse-not-strict-enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the method `parse` won't throw any exception in this case so you should  provide a `ParsePosition` and check that this `index` has been set to the end of the `String` indicating that the entire `String` has been parsed successfully instead of only the beginning.

```
ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
format.parse(value1, parsePosition); // ok
System.out.println(parsePosition.getIndex() == value1.length());
parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
format.parse(value2, parsePosition); // ok, but it's not german format
System.out.println(parsePosition.getIndex() == value2.length());
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```

Comment: Great idea. Thanks

Comment: You could also use `System.out.println(parsePosition.getErrorIndex() == -1)`

Comment: @rasmusgude you should try to call `parsePosition.getErrorIndex()` in both case, you will get `-1` even with `value2` which is not what is expected

Comment: @NicolasFilotto thanks for the update. You are absolutely right, nevermind my comment. Do you know why `getErrorIndex()` is not valid? The documentation states otherwise that and value `12345TEST` seem to behave as expected (getErrorIndex != -1)

Comment: @rasmusgude because the parser doesn't consider it as a parsing error, it simply ignores `.77` and returns `128.598`

Answer (score 3):

Taken from java API

> public abstract Number parse(String source, ParsePosition
> parsePosition)
>
> Returns a Long if possible (e.g., within the range [Long.MIN_VALUE,
> Long.MAX_VALUE] and with no decimals), otherwise a Double. If
> IntegerOnly is set, will stop at a decimal point (or equivalent; e.g.,
> for rational numbers "1 2/3", will stop after the 1). Does not throw
> an exception; if no object can be parsed, index is unchanged!

It's an expected behaviour, the result will be 128.598